# Custom Diasble Directive not working angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, custom-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive for disabling a form field but it's not working.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomDisable]',
  })
 export class CustomDisableDirective {
@Input() appCustomDisable: boolean;
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

ngOnChanges() {
if (this.appCustomDisable) {
  this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 
this.appCustomDisable);
} else {
  this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 
this.appCustomDisable);
 }
}
}
```

I also tried the above using Render from '@angular/core'

```
 this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 
'true');
```

in app.component.html
     I'm using like 
  [appCustomDisable]="myVar"

Stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxb661

Comment: What kind of element are you placing the directive on? Have you added styles to the element which apply when it's disabled? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: And what's wrong with just `[disabled]="someBoolean"` which doesn't need any custom directive?

Comment: Nvm, I can see you're trying to disable a material form control that way. What you're doing is incorrect, as the Material team have already implemented the logic of being able to disable their controls. Look into FormsModule or ReactiveFormsModule and how to disable controls respectively.

Comment: I provided u the stackbliz link. U can get everything from that. I know its not working bcoz the form is not getting disabled.

Comment: I know how to use [disabled]="someBoolean", but i want a custom directive for that where i want to implement some complex functions inside it

Comment: @AnilKumarReddyA implement the function on your component and send the result in the disabled attribute.

Comment: @trichetriche i know that one, but i have to use it in many other places. i want a custom directive for that purpose

Comment: Well seems like you can't have it. As said before, look into Angular form types to see how to handle the disabling of the inputs, and create a service or an utils function that does the heavy lifting.

Comment: @trichetriche see i already went through this. Even this isn't working https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: The control value accessor allows you to **create Angular controls**, not disable them. That's in fact what you are facing : Material has made a control value accessor on their inputs, lockinf it for you. Check template driven and reactive forms, not the control value accessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using MatInput your Code wont work for that. But you can adapt it simply like:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, Optional, S } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material'

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomDisable]'
})
export class CustomDisableDirective {
  @Input() appCustomDisable: string;
  constructor(@Optional() private matInput: MatInput, private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    // Find Input
    let input: any;
    if (this.matInput) {
      // It's a Material Input
      input = this.matInput;
    }
    else {
      // Its a native Input
      if (this.el.nativeElement && this.el.nativeElement.tagName && this.el.nativeElement.tagName === "INPUT") {
        input = this.el.nativeElement;
      } else {
      // No Input found
      // return or throw error
      return;
      }
    }

    if (this.appCustomDisable === 'hide') {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none')
    } else if (this.appCustomDisable === 'view') {
     console.log(input);
     input.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'block')
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: what to do if I'm n't using matInput i.e a normal input tag

Comment: You can use your old code then `let input =document.getElementById("123");
    input.disabled=true`   or in directive like `this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled = true;`

Comment: I tried the above but it's not working. here i created a 
 stackblitz, if possible go through it once  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxb661-nvnrcg

Comment: Because your are still using matInput

Comment: Even if I'm using matInput it should not make difference right, bcoz I'm using input tag? If it's not possible is there any way to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Hello. I've updated my example above. Either it's working as i told you or dont understand your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, what you want to disable is the MatInput directive that is present on the same element. So, just inject it into your component, and disable it:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatInput } from '@angular/material';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomDisable]'
})
export class CustomDisableDirective {

    @Input() appCustomDisable : boolean;
    constructor(private matInput: MatInput) {}

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.matInput.disabled = this.appCustomDisable;
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxb661-jr1kzh?file=app%2Fcustom-disable.directive.ts)

Comment: what to do if I'm n't using matInput i.e if I'm using a a normal input tag